# Is it possible to use "NOCROSSREFS_TO" in linker script for Clang's ld.lld?

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, ld, lld

I need to compile project with custom linker script.

This project is successfully compiled by gcc.

Build fails when I use clang with ld.lld linker.

It fails on linker stage due to the use of "NOCROSSREFS_TO" command, which is used in linker script.

Is it possible to use such a command for ld.lld linker?
Any alternatives?

Comment: Will try to report to bugs-admin@lists.llvm.org...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this command isn't supported.

Comment: It is possible to just comment it out.  The purpose is to provide diagnostics.  For the most part the linkage between GCC and llvm should be the same; with the exceptions of compiler built-ins.  So, if a build is successful with  gcc/gnu ld, then there should be no references from 'text' to 'init' and after a system has booted, the 'init' section could be mapped out of memory (or reused for allocation).  As per [the ticket](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41825).

Comment: @artlessnoise Yes, this is diagnostic command. However it is useful at compilation step. It is like an assert() function calls in C.